# Can a band (i.e. Linkin Park) survive the loss of a core member?

Tags: history, rock, metal

After Chester committed suicide and broke our hearts, I wondered what will happen next?

Will Linkin Park survive? Is there an example from history where bands were able to recover after losing a core member?

My question: can you give an example where bands did manage to recover such a great loss. (Doesn't have to be death, member could also leave for other reason) and remained relevant ?

Comment: I think the 'meat' of this question [& title] needs changing - at present no-one knows whether Linkin Park can survive, that would be purely speculation. The rest of your question, 'did other bands manage to do it?' has much more chance of being answered.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for your reply. Indeed second question was answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to be a bit of a "list question" which isn't great for the SE format, but just for starters [& with no refs, just straight off the top of my head]...

Deaths...

- The Beatles survived the loss of Stuart Sutcliffe - though at the time of his death he was no longer a member of the band.
- The Rolling Stones survived the loss of Brian Jones.
- The Doors tried to keep it together after the death of Jim Morrison, but conceded after a couple of years.
- The Allman Brothers continued after the death of one of the brothers, Duane.
- The Who survived the loss of Keith Moon.
- AC/DC survived the loss of Bon Scott.
- Metallica survived the loss of Cliff Burton.
- Bruce Springsteen's E Street band replaced Clarence Clemons with his nephew, Jake.
- Led Zeppelin did not effectively survive the loss of John Bonham, though they continued in a limited form.
- Queen did not effectively survive the loss of Freddie Mercury, though also continued in a limited form.

Key member leaving for other reasons...

- Fleetwood Mac became more successful after Peter Green left.
- Pink Floyd's impact on the world increased after they removed Syd Barrett.
- Genesis survived after Peter Gabriel left. Each did rather well after the split.
- Depeche Mode survived Vince Clarke leaving. Each had successful careers afterwards.
- Marillion survived the split with Fish, again each having reasonable success afterwards.

Bands who reformed with new line-up, new name...

- Joy Division continued after the death of Ian Curtis, renamed as New Order.
- Nirvana split after the death of Kurt Cobain, but Dave Grohl went on to form the Foo Fighters.

Comment: Gotthard are still around after the tragic death of their frontman Steve Lee in a road accident.

Comment: Nightwish went strong after a bitter breakup with their frontwoman Tarja Turunen. Some critics state that the split was good for both parties

Comment: Thanks for the list. I hope they can recover though LP will never be the same.